# Is node's CRaSH shell disabled with devMode=false?

Tags: corda

When testing Enterprise-DP3, we'd like to turn devMode off. But it seems that disable the shell.  It would be nice to have the shell available even in non devMode during evaluation.

\Sean

Answer (score 0):

The shell is only shown in the local terminal in `devMode`.

Outside of `devMode`, you have to connect to the shell via SSH: https://docs.corda.net/shell.html#the-shell-via-ssh